# but constants in one file and call them in all activities

Tags: java, android

I am making an app that requires the same constants in every activity, so instead of re-writing them I want to put them in one file and call them everywhere, the question is, how to call this constants.class in every activity?

Comment: which type of constants? `String`, `int` etc.. or other typed?

Comment: Why don't you check out the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) which seems to be your answer.

Comment: they are strings only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a `Constants` class and add your constants there, for example:

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String aaa = "StringOne";
    public static final String bbb = "StringTwo";
    public static final int ccc = 3;
}
```

Then from any other activity you can call `Constants.aaa` to get the value `"StringOne"` or `Constants.ccc` to get the int value `3`.

Answer (score 1):

Make a constents class as follows

```
public class Constents 
{
    public static String uname = "uname";
    public static String pwd = "pwd";
    public static String email = "email";
}
```

And you can use this in any Call by Constents.uname